# Utilizing the array value inside JavaScript when creating new object

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, variables

I'm new with using JavaScript and my colleague introduced me to jQuery. Right now I'm testing how to utilize the variables I declare to create progress bars during runtime, and I can't figure out how I can create a `<div>` with its respective counter together with the CSS for animating the progress bar.

Please check variable `counter2` as it is being treated as a string rather than its value inside.

I hope this make sense to everyone and thank you for checking this item.

```js
function clickme2(){
        var values1 = [40,30];
        for (counter2 = 0; counter2 <= 1; counter2++) {
          var css =$(".progressbar[counter2]{height: 20px; background: #4169E1; width: 0; text-align: center; border: 1px;} ")
          $("head").append(css)
          var div =$("<br> <p id = progressnum>this is a progress bar [counter2]</p><div class = 'pp'><div class='progressbar[counter2]'> </div></div>");
          $("body").append(div);
            $('.progressbar').animate(
              {
                width: values1[counter2] + "%"
              },
              {
                duration: 500
              }
            );

        }
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style type='text/css'>
  </style>
  
  <body>
    <br>
      <button id="add" onclick="clickme2()">Add</button>
    <br>
   
   <script>
    //refer to my javascript code
   </script>
   
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To use a variable in a string, you either have to concatenate it, or use a template literal.  If you just stick it inside a string, it will be treated as a string, as that is how javascript is designed.

```
//concatenation
var x = 'me';
var aString = 'Please say hello to '+ x;

//template literal
var x = 'me';
var aString = `Please say hello to ${x}`;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying to my query, I tried it on my end but it didn't work the way I imagine it.

Comment: this is the display result: "counter ${x}"

Comment: @Marcus Take note that that version does not use single or double quotes.  It uses the accent mark.  You must use the accent mark for template literals.